# HTML JS Drop Down Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

beginner here
Trying to create a drop down where the user can select multiple records.
after reading how other have done it, i came up with the below..

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementByID("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;

  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When i delete the STYLE section i get the drop down (with nothing) and the 3 created check box options.
Trying to put them together!!

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. JavaScript is cAsE sEnSiTiVe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted ?

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;

  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, chaged the getElementByID to Id. Thanks guys -.-